# Load csv into html, where to set path to csv?

Tags: jquery, html, csv, path

My embarrasing problem...my brain is not working so early :D

I have a html page where i use a import of a csv file to show status from a job that runs in the background.

Everything worked fine until i have to change the path of my csv file.

Before i had the csv file in the same folder as my html files in the webapp folder from apache.

Now i have to change the path to C:/tmp/ for the csv file.

Iv'e tried many ways to change the function to get it to change the path to C:/tmp/ but i can't get it work.

Where do i have to make the change?

Function look like this now:

```
function()                                        
                {                                        
                $('#csv').load(lnr.val()+'_JobStatus.csv?'+new Date().getTime(),function(data){$(this).html(data).fadeIn("slow");});          });
```

Iv'e tried something like this but it's not working..

```
$('#csv').load('C:/tmp/'+lnr.val()+'_JobStatus.csv?
```

Comment: ok this is fine but what would you do after you upload this to the server ?? you won't have  `c:/temp' there... have you thought about that... i think your approach is not correct .. :)

Comment: Have you tried working with fake path: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68471/the-image-uploader-shows-fakepath-as-path-when-using-chrome

Comment: Hmm i don't really understand your question but i try to explain what i do with the homepage. At my homepage our employees can fill out a form when they make a delivery. They have to fill in a delivery nr and some other infos. After submit the page starts a background job that gets all the values from our db with this delivery number and creates a csv file that automatictly is beeing sent with email to the company for the delivery.

Comment: To check the status of the job i also make a jobstatus.csv file in the job and imports on the webpage when the job is running. With a refresh of that file every 5 sec i get dynamicly infos direkt of the webpage about the job. My jobstatus.csv should be saved locally in C:/tmp/ on the person that starts the jobs an the other files would be saved of the server where the job is.

Answer (score 2):

Try it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#loadData").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "articlename.csv",
        dataType: "text",
        success : function (data) {
            $("#csv").html(data);
        }
    });
 });
});
```

Comment: It musst be some way to change my other code and only make it to search in C:/tmp/ or?